# Select two items with maximum number of common values

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
    +----+-----------+-----------+
    | id | teacherId | studentId |
    +----+-----------+-----------+
    |  1 |         1 |         4 |
    |  2 |         1 |         2 |
    |  3 |         1 |         1 |
    |  4 |         1 |         3 |
    |  5 |         2 |         2 |
    |  6 |         2 |         1 |
    |  7 |         2 |         3 |
    |  8 |         3 |         9 |
    |  9 |         3 |         6 |
    | 10 |         1 |         6 |
    +----+-----------+-----------+
```

I need a query to find two teacherId's with maximum number of common studentId's.
In this case teachers with teacherIds 1,2 have common students with studentIds 2, 1, 3, which is greater than 1,3 having common students 6.
Thanks in Advance!

[Edit]: After several hours I've had the following solution:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT r1tid, r2tid, COUNT(r2tid) AS cnt
    FROM (
        SELECT r1.teacherId AS r1tid, r2.teacherId AS r2tid
        FROM table r1
        INNER JOIN table r2 ON r1.studentId=r2.studentId AND r1.teacherId!=r2.teacherId
        ORDER BY r1tid
    ) t
    GROUP BY r1tid, r2tid
    ORDER BY cnt DESC
    ) t GROUP BY cnt ORDER BY cnt DESC LIMIT 1;
```

I was sure that there must exist more short and elegant solution, but I could not find it.

Comment: Did you ever try answering this question on your own? Show us your attempts and we might help you understanding where they're wrong.

Comment: Yes, I did. I've added my silly attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: I've added the external "select" to be able to group by cnt.

Answer (score 0):

You would do this with a self-join.  Assuming no duplicates in the table:

```
select t.teacherid, t2.teacherid, count(*) as NumStudentsInCommon
from table t join
     table t2
     on t.studentid = t2.studentid and
        t.teacherid < t2.teacherid
group by t.teacherid, t2.teacherid
order by NumStudentsInCommon desc
limit 1;
```

If you had duplicates, you would just replace `count(*)` with `count(distinct studentid)`, but `count(distinct)` requires a bit more work.

Comment: Thank you, Gordon. Your solution looks much more beautiful than mine. It seems to me that I also should replace t.teacherId < t2.teacherId with t.teacherId != t2.teacherId. I still can not get comfortable with the declarative nature of sql :)

Comment: @man213 . . . I put in the `<` because I figured you don't need to list the same pair of teachers twice.  If you want both, then use not equals.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t.teacherId, t2.teacherId, sum(t.studentId) as NumStudentsInCommon
  from table1 t join
   table1 t2
 on t.studentId = t2.studentId and
    t.teacherId < t2.teacherId
 group by t.teacherId, t2.teacherId
 order by NumStudentsInCommon desc
```